# Adding a footnote / thanks to Rmarkdown title slide

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, pandoc, beamer

I have to include a note in my title slide declaring the source of my funding. I was able to do this in LyX / LaTeX through:

```
\author{Michael Chirico\thanks{These people gave me money}, Other Authors}
```

I have not been able to reproduce this in Rmarkdown. The [site](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_pandoc_markdown.html#footnotes) mentions using `[^]` anchoring to mark footnotes, and this works fine in other slides, but I couldn't get it to work in the title:

```
---
title: "Title"
author: "Michael Chirico[^thanks], Other Authors"
date: "February 10, 2016"
output: beamer_presentation

[^thanks]: These people gave me money
---
```

The .pdf compiles but there is no title slide. I think this is the relevant part of the compilation log:

> pandoc: Could not parse YAML header: UnexpectedEvent {_received = Just (EventSequenceStart Nothing), _expected = Nothing} "source" (line 1, column 1)

If I move `[^thanks]` outside the header, the .pdf compiles but there is no footer on the title page (nor anywhere else), and `[^thanks]` appears as-is on the title slide.

How can I add a footnote/thanks section to the title slide?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You could use an [inline note](http://pandoc.org/README.html#footnotes). The regular footnote syntax is `[^note_call]` and then `[^note_call]: note_content` on a new line. Inline notes' syntax is just `^[note_content]`

```
---
title: "Title"
author: "Michael Chirico^[These people gave me money], Other Authors"
date: "February 10, 2016"
output: beamer_presentation
---
```

Another solution that allows more flexibility, but is restricted to the beamer output, would be to change the template.

Comment: this seems perfect. is there any real difference? (besides that mentioned in the link: "unlike regular notes, [inline notes] cannot contain multiple paragraphs")

Comment: I don't think so, pandoc parses both syntax as `Note` elements. You can check by compiling your document with `pandoc -t native`

Comment: For the record this sadly doesn't work on the .Rpres format (not that this was asked in the Q, but I would think the solution would apply to both)

Comment: Does not work in general Rmarkdown documents either, as of November 2017.